# How to pass parameters value from a template yaml file to main pipeline

Tags: templates, azure-devops, parameters, yaml, azure-pipelines

when i try to run this pipeline on azure devops, i got the error "Unexpected property RunChangeLogic". How can I troubleshoot this?

It seems it doesn't accept the parameter from the template EntryPoint.yaml. Is there anything else I need to do?
sorry for the simple question like this. I am completely new to Azure Devops

*EntryPoint.yaml:*

```
parameters:

  - name: RunChangeLogic  
    displayName: Run change logic  
    type: boolean  
    default: false  
....
```

*Azure_pipeline.yaml:*

```
trigger: none  

pool:  
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  

stages:  
  - template: "YamlTemplates/Stage/Entrypoint.yaml"  
    parameters:  
       RunChangeLogic: 'true'
```

Comment: "can you please help me troubleshoot it?"  can only be correctly answered by `yes` or `no`. Stackoverflow is not the place to ask about the capabilities of others, instead ask a question for which the answer would help you solve the problem. You can properly format code/data by selecting the block and indenting it four spaces with Ctrl+K.

Comment: Hello Pardis, I tested with the script your provided but everything work perfectly. And according to the error message, the issue probably caused by Incorrect indent format. I suggest you provide a more complete template file to let us know how you use the the `RunChangeLogic` parameter.

Comment: I am not sure why but now i am getting a different error messagev "/Data/Pipelines/YamlTemplates/Stage/Entrypoint.yaml (Line: 23, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages' "    . EntryPoint.yaml has been written by  a professional and have already been used in different pipelines so i am sure it doesn't have any problem.  (unfortunately, i am unable to put the whole file here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your yaml and it works for me with following yaml.

[image]

Entrypoint.yaml:

```
parameters:

  - name: RunChangeLogic  
    displayName: Run change logic  
    type: boolean  
    default: false  

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.RunChangeLogic }}
```

Azure_pipeline.yaml:

```
trigger: none  

pool:  
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  

extends:
   template: "YamlTemplates/Stage/Entrypoint.yaml"  
   parameters:  
       RunChangeLogic: 'true'
```

For more info please refer the official Doc [Template types & usage.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

---

Edit:
From your comment, I understand that you have a multi stage azure pipeline. Please refer to this [stages.template definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-template?view=azure-pipelines).

> You can define a set of stages in one file and use it multiple times in other files.

Here is my test yaml files for stages template.

Entrypoint.yaml:

```
parameters:

  - name: RunChangeLogic  
    displayName: Run change logic  
    type: boolean  
    default: false  

stages:
- stage: Teststage1
  jobs:
  - job: ${{ parameters.RunChangeLogic }}_testjob1
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.RunChangeLogic }}
- stage: Teststage2
  jobs:
  - job: ${{ parameters.RunChangeLogic }}_testjob2
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.RunChangeLogic }}
```

Azure_pipeline.yaml:

```
trigger: none  

pool:  
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  

stages:
- template: "YamlTemplates/Stage/Entrypoint.yaml"  
  parameters: 
    RunChangeLogic: 'true'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. if I want to have a multi stage azure pipeline can i still use "extends"?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. it seems the error was because of the other stage I had on the Azure_pipeline.yaml file. it is working fine now :)

Comment: It is great that it's working fine now.